# split httpd in smaller files

Tags: httpd

Hi I need to extract each VirtualHosts from my httpd.conf to separate files for easier management.

Original httpd.conf
.

```
..
<VirtualHost *:XXXX>
  SuexecUserGroup user1 groupX
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:XXXY>
  SuexecUserGroup user2 groupY
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:XXYY>
  SuexecUserGroup user3 groupZ
  ...
</VirtualHost>
...
```

And I would like to have files like:
- XXXX_user1.conf containing:

```
Listen XXXX
<VirtualHost *:XXXX>
  SuexecUserGroup user1 groupX
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

- XXXY_user2.conf containing:

```
Listen XXXY
<VirtualHost *:XXXY>
  SuexecUserGroup user2 groupY
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Sounds a bit complicated but I have like 500 to do by hand ;(

Many thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    RS = "</VirtualHost>\n"
}
{
    prefix = gensub("*:([^>]*)>", "\\1", "1", $2)
    filename = prefix "_" $4 ".conf"
    print "Listen " prefix "\n" $0 "\n" RS > filename
}
```

Save it in a file named, perhaps, "httpdsplit" and do:

```
$ chmod u+x httpdsplit
$ ./httpdsplit httpd.conf
```

Comment: I've tweaked a bit the script so it adds also Listen XXXX at the beginning:
.    
    #!/usr/bin/gawk -f
    BEGIN {
        RS = "</VirtualHost>\n"
    }
    {
        prefix = gensub("*:([^>]*)>", "\\1", "1", $2)
        filename = prefix "_" $4 ".conf"
        print "Listen "prefix $0 "" RS > filename
    }

Comment: @Warnaud: Oops, sorry, I forgot to add that part. I'll edit my answer. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: I would like to really since it's exactly what I was looking for but ... how to do that :( ?
The site is great but the syntax and this kind of options are quite invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Though you didn't mention it, this looks like apache httpd.conf.  Though I recommend the existing answer which splits the files, there is another option.

**If** the apache server is built with `mod_perl` and **if** you know (or are willing to learn) Perl, remember that `mod_perl` binds with all aspects of apache, including config.  You could write the config with a Perl stanza and generate the VirtualHost config within perl itself.